# Is the Sorgenfrey line a P-space?

Tags: general-topology

The [Sorgenfrey line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lower_limit_topology) is $\mathbb R$ with the topology generated by the basis of the half open intervals $[a,b)$ where $a,b \in \mathbb R$.
$X$ is a [P-space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-space) if every countable intersection of open sets in $X$ is open.

Is Sorgenfrey line a P-space?

I think that it is, since the intersection of a countable number of open basis sets, is an open basis sets.

Am I right?

Thank you!

Comment: A first countable $T_1$ space is a P-space if and only if it is discrete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not. Consider the intersection $$\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} [0, 1+\frac{1}{n}) = [0,1]$$

This is not open since there is no open neighborhood of 1 contained in [0,1]. Nice question though!

Comment: yes.. i see. Thank you!